# How to create a Zip file using gradle 2.3

Tags: gradle

I have my archive at location `myProject/unzip` and need to:

**Zip** the contents within the unzip folder and create a zip file with some name at any location within the project.

Using `gradle 2.3`.

Can anyone help me for this?

Comment: Use a [zip task](https://docs.gradle.org/2.3/userguide/working_with_files.html#createZip)? Also, why are you on such an old version of Gradle :/

Comment: I'm using the old version because already the project uses that particular version.Also, I tried all possible solutions to create a zip. But nothing seems to work.

Comment: task myZip(type: Zip){
 println "create zip"
 from (fileTree('/opt/calypso/akila/unzip'))

}
This is the code...Build is successfull, but no zip is created

Comment: /opt/calypso/akila/build/distributions/akila-1.0.zip
Also in output, it is showing the zip file has been created in the distributions

Comment: I tried refreshing my distributions, but the file isnt present

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are doing differently than the examples in the documentation from the [link](https://docs.gradle.org/2.3/userguide/working_with_files.html#createZip) I gave in the comments. But this works for me with Gradle 2.3:

```
task myZip(type: Zip){
    from "$projectDir/unzip"
    archiveName = "my-zip.zip"
    destinationDir = buildDir
}
```

The input folder is called `unzip` and needs to present as a child in the project folder. It outputs a file `my-zip.zip` in the `build` folder.

Be sure that there actually are some resources located in the `from` path, or Gradle might skip it.